# Use Bootstrap PHP Form wizard insert into sql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to learn PHP and came across Bootstrap Form wizard and wanted to give it a try.

I have made a basic registration form which should basically INSERT the values from the form to the database.

With normal form i have successfully registered using form submit button. But with this wizard i do not have a submit button, with few research i found that this type of form is handled with jquery and so on. I needed to understand how can i go ahead and use these forms to insert data into my database with POST.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once 'dbConnect.php';

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emp_table WHERE user_id=". $_SESSION['user']."");
    $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);    
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
      <meta name="description" content="A fully featured admin theme which can be used to build CRM, CMS, etc.">
      <meta name="author" content="Coderthemes">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon_1.ico">
      <title>Create New Customer</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plugins/jquery.steps/demo/css/jquery.steps.css">
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="css/core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="css/components.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="css/icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="css/pages.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
      <script src="js/modernizr.min.js"></script>
      <script>(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
         (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
         m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
         })(window,document,'script','../www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

         ga('create', '0', 'auto');
         ga('send', 'pageview');
      </script>

</head>
    <body class="fixed-left">

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="topbar">
            <?php include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/topbarleft.php'; ?>
                <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="">
                            <?php include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/topbarpullleft.php'; ?>
                            <?php include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/topbarright.php'; ?>
                                <div class="left side-menu">
                                    <div class="sidebar-inner slimscrollleft">
                                        <div class="user-details">
                                            <div class="pull-left">
                                                <img src="images/users/avatar-1.jpg" alt="" class="thumb-md img-circle">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="user-info">
                                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><?php echo $userRow['user_login_id']; ?></a>
                                            <p class="text-muted m-0"><?php echo $userRow['user_role']; ?></p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="sidebar-menu">
                                            <ul>
                                                <?php include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/menu.php'; ?>
                                                <?php
                                                    if($userRow['user_role']=="Manager" || $userRow['user_role']=="Team Leader")
                                                        {
                                                ?>
                                                <?php include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/menureporting.php'; ?>
                                                <?php
                                                        }
                                                ?>
                                                <?php
                                                    if($userRow['user_admin']=="Yes")
                                                        {
                                                ?>
                                                <?php include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/menuadmin.php'; ?>
                                                <?php
                                                        }
                                                ?>
                                            </ul>
                                            <div class="clearfix">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="clearfix">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>  
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-page">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <h4 class="page-title">Create New Customer</h4>
                                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                                    <li><a href="#">SystemTech</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Customers</a></li>
                                    <li class="active">Create New Customer</li>
                                </ol>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="card-box">
                                <h4 class="m-t-0 header-title"><b>Creating new customer</b></h4>
                                    <form id="wizard-validation-form" method="post" action="createcust.php">
                                        <div>
                                            <h3>Personal Detail</h3>
                                                <section>
                                                    <div class="form-group clearfix">
                                                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="cust_first_name">First name</label>
                                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                            <input class="required form-control" id="cust_first_name" name="cust_first_name" type="text">
                                                            </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group clearfix">
                                                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="cust_last_name">Last Name</label>
                                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                            <input class="required form-control" id="cust_last_name" name="cust_last_name" type="text">
                                                            </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group clearfix">
                                                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="cust_email_id">Email ID</label>
                                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                            <input type="email" class="required form-control" id="cust_email_id" placeholder="Email" name="cust_email_id">
                                                            </div>
                                                    </div>  
                                                </section>
                                            <h3>Contact Detail</h3>
                                                <section>
                                                    <div class="form-group clearfix">
                                                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="cust_contact_no">Contact Number</label>
                                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                            <input type="text" placeholder="" data-mask="(999) 999-9999" class="required form-control" name="cust_contact_no"> <span class="font-13 text-muted">(999) 999-9999</span>
                                                            </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group clearfix">
                                                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="cust_alt_contact_no">Alt. Contact Number</label>
                                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                            <input type="text" placeholder="" data-mask="(999) 999-9999" class="required form-control" name="cust_alt_contact_no"> <span class="font-13 text-muted">(999) 999-9999</span>
                                                            </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </section>
                                                <h3>Billing Address</h3>
                                                <section>
                                                    <div class="form-group clearfix">
                                                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="cust_bill_addr">Address</label>
                                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                            <input id="cust_bill_addr" name="cust_bill_addr" type="text" class="form-control" value="Customer Address">
                                                            </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group clearfix">
                                                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="cust_country">Country</label>
                                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                            <input id="cust_country" name="cust_country" type="text" class="required form-control">
                                                            </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group clearfix">
                                                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="cust_state">State</label>
                                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                            <input id="cust_state" name="cust_state" type="text" class="required form-control">
                                                            </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group clearfix">
                                                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="cust_zip">ZIP Code</label>
                                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                            <input id="cust_zip" name="cust_zip" type="text" class="required form-control">
                                                            </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </section>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <script>var resizefunc = [];</script>
      <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/detect.js"></script>
      <script src="js/fastclick.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
      <script src="js/waves.js"></script>
      <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery.core.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery.app.js"></script>
      <script src="plugins/bootstrapvalidator/dist/js/bootstrapValidator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="plugins/jquery.steps/build/jquery.steps.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
      <script src="pages/jquery.wizard-init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="plugins/autoNumeric/autoNumeric.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">jQuery(function($) {
         $('.autonumber').autoNumeric('init');    
         });
      </script>
      <script src="plugins/bootstrap-inputmask/bootstrap-inputmask.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

jquery:

```js
! function(a) {
    "use strict";
    var b = function() {};
    b.prototype.createBasic = function(a) {
        return a.children("div").steps({
            headerTag: "h3",
            bodyTag: "section",
            transitionEffect: "slideLeft"
        }), a
    }, b.prototype.createValidatorForm = function(a) {
        return a.validate({
            errorPlacement: function(a, b) {
                b.after(a)
            }
        }), a.children("div").steps({
            headerTag: "h3",
            bodyTag: "section",
            transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
            onStepChanging: function(b, c, d) {
                return a.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden", a.valid()
            },
            onFinishing: function(b, c) {
                return a.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled", a.valid()
            },
            onFinished: function(a, b) {
    type:"POST"
                alert("Submitted!")
            }
        }), a
    }, b.prototype.createVertical = function(a) {
        return a.steps({
            headerTag: "h3",
            bodyTag: "section",
            transitionEffect: "fade",
            stepsOrientation: "vertical"
        }), a
    }, b.prototype.init = function() {
        this.createBasic(a("#basic-form")), this.createValidatorForm(a("#wizard-validation-form")), this.createVertical(a("#wizard-vertical"))
    }, a.FormWizard = new b, a.FormWizard.Constructor = b
}(window.jQuery),
function(a) {
    "use strict";
    a.FormWizard.init()
}(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: old mysql sintax,sql injections, got a lot more to learn i sugest w3school

Comment: True.. I thought i would go with basics understand things and then explore new options.

Comment: madalin can you please suggest how can i make this form submit in MySQL so i get a start here i am kind of stuck and searching for options to understand.

Comment: learn about forms and about input type submit see w3school

Comment: I am okay with submit button when it is there i am able to a successful insert. But with this type of form where there is no Submit Button and the Finish button is called from this bootstrap i want to understand how can i insert the form data.

Comment: learn about ajax if you want to do this with javascript

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95234/discussion-between-sumeet-pujari-and-madalin-ivascu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `serialize()` form using it's ID, and send it via POST to a php file that will save them to the DB

```
$.ajax({
            url: "save_to_db.php",
            data: $("#form_to_send").serialize(),
            type: "POST",
            success: function (result) {
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
              alert("Sorry, there was a problem!");
              console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
              console.log("Status: " + status);
              console.dir(xhr);
            }
        });
```

`$field1 = $_POST['field1']` and so on...